# JQuery - parametized calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of input fields that should show, if their corresponding paired checkbox is checked.

My problem here is that the checkbox corresponds to an inputfield. 
Do I have to parse the checkbox number to the function as parameter so the click function can be called correctly? Or how do I approach this.

In my example, you can see that I have a click function on my first checkbox, but I want the function to be general and I want only to parse the cb number, how can I do that in JQuery?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("input.ui-spinner").spinner({
                min: 5,
                max: 15000,
                step: 5,
                start: 100,
                numberFormat: "d"
            });
            $("#cb\\[1\\]").click(function () {
                $("#cspinner\\[1\\]").val('0');
                $("#cspinner\\[1\\]").toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
<ul class="checkbox">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb[1]" name="cb[1]" value="pepperoni" /><label for="cb[1]">Pepperoni</label>
    <input id="cspinner[1]" class="ui-spinner" style="display: none;" name="cspinner" size="5" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
 </li>
 <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb[2]" name="cb[2]" value="sausage" /><label for="cb[2]">Sausage</label>
    <input id="cspinner[2]" class="ui-spinner" style="display: none;" name="cspinner" size="5" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
 </li>
 <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb[3]" name="cb[3]" value="mushrooms" /><label for="cb[3]">Mushrooms</label>
    <input id="cspinner[3]" class="ui-spinner" style="display: none;" name="cspinner" size="5" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to have on each chekbox different ID? What about to have a class for checkboxes and find second by function .sibling()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$("[id^='cb[']").click(function () {
    var num = this.id.replace('cb[', '').replace(']', '');
    $("#cspinner\\[" + num + "\\]").val('0');
    $("#cspinner\\[" + num + "\\]").toggle();
});
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/MG6Zj/

Comment: For some reason I like this approach a little. Most because with siblings, I am locking my pairs together, like a marriage. This approach is more like an open relationship. (not reflecting my preferences in marital vies) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input[id*="cb"]').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings('input').val('0');
            $(this).siblings('input').toggle();
        });
```

You can use more generic selectors than you are using.

http://jsfiddle.net/zaacj/

Comment: Why are you searching sibling element twice? I think this is better and faster: `$(this).siblings('input').val('0').toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add class and then use transitional function .siblings() to find next input...

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("input.ui-spinner").spinner({
            min: 5,
            max: 15000,
            step: 5,
            start: 100,
            numberFormat: "d"
        });
        $(".myCheck").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings(".ui-spinner").val('0').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<ul class="checkbox">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" name="cb[1]" value="pepperoni" /><label     for="cb[1]">Pepperoni</label>
    <input class="ui-spinner" style="display: none;" name="cspinner" size="5" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
 </li>
 <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" name="cb[2]" value="sausage" /><label for="cb[2]">Sausage</label>
    <input class="ui-spinner" style="display: none;" name="cspinner" size="5" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
 </li>
 <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" name="cb[3]" value="mushrooms" /><label for="cb[3]">Mushrooms</label>
    <input class="ui-spinner" style="display: none;" name="cspinner" size="5" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
 </li>
</ul>
```